# How display in angular app data that is available at the given link in JSON file

Tags: json, angular

I displayed in my Angular app list of poem's titles using this API: https://wolnelektury.pl/api/authors/krzysztof-kamil-baczynski/books/?format=json

After clicking on chosen title on my website I want to display poem. But in my JSON file I have only URL, not poem's text. Can I display in any way data that is available at the given link in JSON file on my own?